# What is a simple way to combine two Emacs major modes, or to change an existing mode?

Tags: r, emacs, latex, dot-emacs

In Emacs, I'm working with a file that is a hybrid of two languages.

**Question 1: Is there a simple way to write a major mode file that combines two major modes?**

Details:

- The language is called "brew" (not the "BREW" of "Binary Runtime Environment for Wireless").
- brew is made up of the languages R and Latex, whose modes are R-mode and latex-mode.
- The R code appears between the tags <% and %>. Everything else is Latex.
- How can I write a brew-mode.el file? (Or is one already available?)

One idea, which I got from this [posting](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/perl-modperl/200002.mbox/%3CNDBBIDIMBKMLMLLCGCNAEEFPCBAA.jreid@ocireland.com%3E), is to use Latex mode, and treat the code of the form  <% ... %> as a comment.

Comment: Please ask question 2 as a new SO question.

Comment: Trey, thank you for the suggestion. The post is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750563/in-emacs-how-do-you-change-latex-mode-to-treat-as-a-comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A number of folks have written solutions enabling you to use multiple major modes at once.  See the Emacs Wiki for [Multiple Modes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes).  I personally have no experience with them and cannot recommend one over another.

Comment: I've worked with MuMaMo in nxhtml and it works pretty well most of the time.

Comment: @Trey: thank you for the link. I changed the two-mode-mode.el file there, and got it to work. But in Latex mode (not R mode), the minibuffer was constantly printing messages. Possibly Emacs was in an infinite loop. I used Aquamacs (Emacs) 1.9 on Mac OS 10.6.3. Your experience with two-mode-mode might differ. @Bozhidar: Thank you for the information.