# In Emacs, how do you change Latex mode to treat <% ... %> as a comment?

Tags: latex, elisp

In Emacs, is there some short code that you can write (in .emacs, latex.el, or some other file) so that Latex mode treats code of form <% ... %> as a comment?

Comment: As far as I can see, the problem with this is that _LaTeX_ doesn't treat that as comment.

Comment: Are you trying to get it to syntax highlight that for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

See [this tutorial on writing syntax highlighting support for new modes](http://web.archive.org/web/20070702002238/http://two-wugs.net/emacs/mode-tutorial.html) (wayback machine link to material orriginally found at http://two-wugs.net/emacs/mode-tutorial.html and attibuted to Scott Andrew Borton), then dig into what the latex mode you are using (tex-mode? auctex? something else?) is doing and fix it.

Which only leaves the question: **Why?!?**

Comment: There are some template systems that use `<%` and `%>` as their delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `font-lock-add-keyword` function; give it a major mode to add keywords too, and a association list of regex / face:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'latex-mode
   '(("\<\%.*\%\>" . font-lock-comment-face)))
```

More details here on emacswiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AddKeywords

**Note** this answer was copied over from the [previous version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738322/what-is-a-simple-way-to-combine-two-emacs-major-modes-or-to-change-an-existing)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following might work:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?< "_ 1n" latex-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?% "< 23" latex-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?> "_ 4n" latex-mode-syntax-table)
```